# Order the following big O notation, from the fastest running time to slowest

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Order the following big O notation, from the fastest running time to slowest running time.

- 1000
- 2^n
- n ln⁡ n
- 2n^2
- n

My attempt/guess is

- 2^n,
- 2n^2,
- n ln⁡ n,
- 1000

Am I even close?
Time complexity is a very confusing topic. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Just let n=10000 and put everything into its place, that will be enough for this particular problem.

Comment: You've got it backwards.

Comment: ...what about `n`?

Comment: SO, it would be 1000, n ln⁡〖n,〗  n, 2n^2,2^n,?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an image I found on the web:

[image]

You should keep in mind that

- `1000` is a constant, i.e. it is in `O(1)`.
- if a function `f(x)` is in `O(...)`, then any scaled version `k*f(x)` obtained by multiplication with a constant `k` is in the same class `O(...)`.
- as suggested by @Gassa, inserting a large number for `n` is in many cases "good enough" to understand which of two classes is "faster" (i.e. `ln(10000) < sqrt(10000)" => O(ln(n)) is lower than O(sqrt(n)))

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great! So, it should be 1000, n ln⁡〖n,〗  n, 2n^2,2^n,

Comment: Look at the `n log(n)` vs `n` curve again or insert a large `n`. The rest is fine.

Comment: ANSWER: 1000,  n,  n ln⁡〖n,   〗 2n^2,〖 2〗^n, Thank you!

Comment: LOL, as soon as I gain my last reputation, I can accept it. Im still a newbz.